# Preprocessor keywords inside templates in C

Tags: c

I would like to define a template like this:

```
 #define DECLARE_MY_STRUCT(name) \
 #ifndef MY_STRUCT_DECLARED \
 struct my_##name##_struct { \
   double var; \
 }; \
 #define MY_STRUCT_DECLARED \
 #endif
```

This would allow me to use DECLARE_MY_STRUCT template wherever I want and not get "my_struct was already defined" error.

Unfortunately, gcc treats #ifndef as its preprocessor directives instead of part of template declaration and fails to build such code. Any way to workaround this?
( Except for using

```
 #ifndef MY_X_STRUCT_DECLARED
  DECLARE_MY_STRUCT(X)
 #endif
```

as there may be a lot of different struct names.
)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this approach? Maybe there's a better way to solve your specific problem without using strange constructs.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with very old C project and can't change its nature. I'm trying to define structs with templates bcs there may be a lot of them and they shall have different typenames. The problem is that my code is then copied into the same sourcefile with double replaced by float in function prototypes. I can't change this step. That leads to 2 calls of same template in same sourcefile and clashing struct declarations.

Comment: So you really need two different structs, one with `double` members and one with `float` members, no? Why not make the precision a template parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C Standard does not allow nested pre-processor directives, so this is impossible. The `#` in `#ifndef` would be treated as a stringizing `#`.